# Raster .tif image faceting in R

Tags: raster, r, tmap

How do I facet a .tif image using the tmap package.

I have read and plotted an image using `tm_raster()` function. Now, I want to facet it elevation range/group.

```
raster_img <- raster("n08_e007_3arc_v2.tif")

tm_shape(raster_img) +
  tm_raster() + 
  tm_facets(by='elevation')
```

All examples on the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tmap/versions/3.3-2/topics/tm_facets) uses vector or DEM/DSM layers for the faceting. Is it possible to facet a raster .tif image?

Comment: How do you want to present an elevation map with a given range? For example do you want the first facet to show the elevation between 0 and 100, with blank areas elsewhere, and then the next facet to show elevations between 100 and 200 with blank above and below?

Comment: The elevation range is at 200 interval, that is: 0-200, 200-400, 400-600, 600-800, 800-1000